# How to make tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath) with multiple UITableViewCell readable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with multiple `UITableViewCell`, every cell have a different design and high, the problem I have that now the method tableView(`cellForRowAtIndexPath`) look so weird and unreadable and I don't know if this is the true and the good practice implementation for the case.

My method :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if(indexPath.section == 0){ // linked news item
            let cellIdentifier = "linkedNewsTableViewCell";
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LinkedNewsTableViewCell;
            let linked_news = LinkedNews[indexPath.row];
            cell.newTitle.text = linked_news.news_title;
            return cell;
        }else if(indexPath.section > 1 && indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section != sections.count+2){ // section header item
            let cellIdentifier = "sectionHeaderTableViewCell";
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderTableViewCell;
            let sec = sections[indexPath.section-2];
            cell.lblSectionTitle.text = sec.section_name;
            cell.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.lightGray;
            return cell;
        }else if(indexPath.section == 2+sections.count){ // all rights reserved item
            let cellIdentifier = "allRightsReservedTableViewCell";
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AllRightsReservedTableViewCell;
            cell.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.lightGray;
            return cell;
        }else if(indexPath.section == 1){ // slider news item
            let cellIdentifier = "newsTableViewCell";
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell;
            cell.imgVideo.hidden = true;
            let newsItem = SliderNews[indexPath.row];
            cell.txtNews.text = newsItem.news_title;
            cell.lblTime.text = Utilities.timeAgoSinceDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:newsItem.createdstamp!), numericDates: false);
            do{
            let isSaved = try DBManger.sharedInstance.isSaved(String(newsItem.news_id!));
            cell.isSaved = isSaved;
            cell.news = newsItem;
                if(isSaved == true){
                    cell.btnSave.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_bookmark_blue"), forState: .Normal);
                }else{
                    cell.btnSave.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_bookmark"), forState: .Normal);
                }
            }catch{

            }

            if(SliderNews.count-1 == indexPath.row){
                cell.buttomLine.hidden = true;
            }else{
                cell.buttomLine.hidden = false;
            }

            let image = cell.imgNews.getImage(newsItem.image!, timestamp: String(newsItem.createdstamp!), size: "228", qualty: "70");

            cell.imgNews.loadImage(image,contentMode: .ScaleToFill)

            cell.lblType.text = newsItem.section_name;
            cell.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.lightGray;
            return cell;
        }else{ // section news item
            let sec = sections[indexPath.section-2];
            if(indexPath.row == sec.news.count+1){
                let cellIdentifier = "moreNewsTableViewCell";
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MoreNewsTableViewCell;
                cell.lblSectionName.text = "المزيد من \(sec.section_name!)";
                cell.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.lightGray;
                return cell;
            }
            let cellIdentifier = "newsTableViewCell";
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell;
            cell.imgVideo.hidden = true;
            let newsItem = sec.news[indexPath.row-1];
            cell.txtNews.text = newsItem.news_title;
            cell.lblTime.text = Utilities.timeAgoSinceDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:newsItem.createdstamp!), numericDates: false);
            cell.lblType.text = sec.section_name;

            if(sec.news.count == indexPath.row){
                cell.buttomLine.hidden = true;
            }else{
                cell.buttomLine.hidden = false;
            }

            let image = cell.imgNews.getImage(newsItem.image!, timestamp: String(newsItem.createdstamp!), size: "228", qualty: "70");

            cell.imgNews.loadImage(image,contentMode: .ScaleToFill)

            cell.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.lightGray;

            do{
                let isSaved = try DBManger.sharedInstance.isSaved(String(newsItem.news_id!));
                cell.isSaved = isSaved;
                cell.news = newsItem;
                if(isSaved == true){
                    cell.btnSave.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_bookmark_blue"), forState: .Normal);
                }else{
                    cell.btnSave.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_bookmark"), forState: .Normal);
                }
            }catch{

            }

            return cell;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The same question xD

Comment: Use Fabric pattern, pass to it interface `cellIdentifier`and return done cell, or  use Builder pattern and implement the same logic, up to you. I think you need read Design Pattern:)

Comment: make cell class take care of setting up and use switch instead of that mess

Comment: Can you share me the document of Fabric pattern please? :D

Comment: @iSashok i know my code not that good . can u give me resource about the design pattern that i should use or any good and clean code to read and learn from .

Comment: The common desc in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns and about Factory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern . And i recommend you read this book http://www.apress.com/9781484203958

Comment: @iSashok thank u !

Comment: Use `switch indexPath.section` and `case 0...` would make it better, and you also can separate those into multiple function to be easier to read like `func createFirstCell(row: NSIndexPath) -> CustomCell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with your code, you have a few issues thats needs to be resolved before the code can look much better:

**1.** You need a model that reflects your tableView data source , it should look something like:

```
    let currentSectionModel = self.sections[indexPath.section] 
    let currentRowModel = currentSectionModel[]
```

and then you can use something more generic with your cells to set the model object:

```
cell.setRowModel(currentRowModel)
```

**2.** Your if statements that decides witch section to present, are very complicated,

```
for example this line:

    if indexPath.section > 1 && indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section != sections.count+2 {
```

You have to find a better logic for this. Once you orgenize the model like I sad in section 1, This should look much more clear and you can change it to a switch statement, that questions an enum.

**3.** All cell logic, I prefer to do Inside the cell itself, for cleaner viewController, I've done so at the example code at the end.

**4.** Don't use strings for identifier, It can cause bugs. that's the reason I prefer to use an extension on UITableViewCell witch returns the class name as the identifier.

**5.** Don't use semi columns is swift.

**6.** All your cells should have a base class, that way you can use polymorphism when returning cells.

**7.** Once you have a model that represent the data source, you can use Switch statement instead of if statement.

This is the example code I've written, you have to work on your code a bit before it will compile. I'ts just a better practice example. (I didn't use switch statements only because your cases are too complexed to use a simple enum. Like I sad, I'ts something you have to work on, and make it more simple)

```
class BaseCellType: UITableViewCell {
}

class AllRightsReservedTableViewCell: BaseCellType {
    // Your implementation
}

class LinkedNewsTableViewCell: BaseCellType {
    func setLinkedNews(linedNews: LinkedNews) {
        // Your implementation
    }
}

class SectionHeaderTableViewCell: BaseCellType {
    func setSectionModel(sectionModel: SectionModel) {
     // Your implementation
    }
}

class MoreNewsTableViewCell: BaseCellType {
    func setSection(section: SectionModel) {
     // Your implementation
    }
}

class NewsTableViewCell: BaseCellType {
    // Your implementation
}

class SectionsModel {
    let rows: [RowModel]
}

extension UITableViewCell {
    static var cellIdentifer: String {
        get {
            return String(self.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString("__").last!
        }
    }
}

enum SectionType: Int {
    case AllRightsReserevedSection = 1, LinkedNewItem = 0
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var sections: [SectionsModel]!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: BaseCellType

        switch (section: indexPath.section,row: indexPath.row) {
        case (SectionType.AllRightsReserevedSection.rawValue, _):
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AllRightsReservedTableViewCell.cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AllRightsReservedTableViewCell;
        case (SectionType.LinkedNewItem.rawValue, _):
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(LinkedNewsTableViewCell.cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LinkedNewsTableViewCell;
            cell.setLinkedNews(LinkedNews[indexPath.row])
        case let index where index.section > 1 , index.row == 0, index.section != secrion+2:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SectionHeaderTableViewCell.cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderTableViewCell
            cell.setSectionModel(sections[indexPath.section-2])
        case let index where index.section == section.count + 2:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AllRightsReservedTableViewCell.cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AllRightsReservedTableViewCell;
        case let index where index.row == (sec.news.count + 1) :
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(MoreNewsTableViewCell.cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MoreNewsTableViewCell;
            cell.setSection(sections[indexPath.section-2])
        default:
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NewsTableViewCell.cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell;
                cell.setNewsItem(sec.news[indexPath.row-1])
            }
        }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
func makeBasicTableCell(title:String,details:String,indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CustomHeaderCell{
            let cell = tableProfile.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomHeaderCell
            cell.titleLable.text = title
            cell.detLable.text = details
            return cell
     }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var tblCell: UITableViewCell!
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "profile_details", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            switch(indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                return makeBasicTableCell("Text1", details: "TextDetail1", indexPath: indexPath)
            case 1:
                return makeBasicTableCell("Text2", details: "TextDetail2", indexPath: indexPath)
            case 2:
                return makeBasicTableCell("Text3", details: "TextDetail3", indexPath: indexPath)
            case 3:
                return makeBasicTableCell("Text4", details: "TextDetail4", indexPath: indexPath)
            default:
                return makeBasicTableCell("", details: "", indexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }  else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            switch(indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                return makeBasicTableCell("Text5", details: "TextDetail5", indexPath: indexPath)
            case 1:
                return makeBasicTableCell("Text6", details: "TextDetail6", indexPath: indexPath)
            case 2:
                return makeBasicTableCell("Text7", details: "TextDetail7", indexPath: indexPath)
            default:
                return makeBasicTableCell("", details: "", indexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }
        return tblCell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  -> *Objective-C

```
if(your first condition){ 
          static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
          MANewsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableView.rowHeight=30;
            }else if(second condition ){ 
          static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell1";
          MANewsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableView.rowHeight=40;
            }else 
    {
          static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell2";
          MANewsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableView.rowHeight=50;
    }
```

I hope I help you.